# Prove that $ P[X \leq x - \epsilon] - P[|X_n - X| \geq \epsilon ] \leq P[X_n \leq x] \leq P[X \leq x + \epsilon] + P[|X_n - x| \geq \epsilon] $?

Tags: probability

I've Tried to use $P(AB) \leq P(A) + P(B)$, but it seems doesn't work for me, I still can't figure it out after a long time.

Here is the inequality：

$$ P[X \leq x - \epsilon] - P[|X_n - X| \geq \epsilon ] \leq P[X_n \leq x] \leq P[X \leq x + \epsilon]  + P[|X_n - x| \geq \epsilon] $$

Both $X$ and $X_n$ are random variables.

Thankyou so much!

Comment: There is a typo in the last term. You have typed $|X_n-x|$ instead of $|X_n-X|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(X \leq x-\epsilon) \subseteq (|X_n-X| >\epsilon) \cup (X_n \leq x)$ because if $X\leq x-\epsilon$ but the inequality $|X_n-X| >\epsilon$ fails then we get $X_n \leq X+(X_n-X) \leq (x-\epsilon) +\epsilon =x$. It follows that $P(X \leq x-\epsilon) \leq P(|X_n-X| >\epsilon)+P((X_n \leq x)$. Now transfer the first term on RHS to the left side. 
The other inequality is proved in a similar way. [$(X_n\leq x) \subseteq (|X_n-X|\geq \epsilon) \cup (X\leq x+\epsilon)$].